# While loop reading only last line?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, shell

i want to print all array data of foo line by line but this loop is
printing last line of string of array it is not printing all line of
array variable please help.

```
foo=( $(grep name  emp.txt) ) 
while read -r line ; do echo "$line"
done <<< ${foo[@]}
```

Comment: `printf '%s\n' "${foo[@]}"` to print each element of the foo array on a new line.

Comment: `while read -r line; do echo "$line"; done < <(grep 'name' emp.txt)`

Comment: thanks a lot david its working now.

Comment: i want to replace some text can i use sed command in echo "$line" - @DavidC.Rankin

Answer (score 2):

While David C. Rankin presented a working alternative, he chose to not explain why the original approach didn't work. See the [**Bash Reference Manual: Word Splitting**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html):

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command
>   substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within
>   double quotes for word splitting.

So, you can make your approach work by using double quotes around the command substitution as well as the parameter expansion:

```
foo=("$(grep name emp.txt)") 
while read -r line; do echo "$line"
done <<<"${foo[@]}"
```

Note that this assigns the whole `grep` output to the sole array element `${foo[0]}`, i. e., we don't need an array at all and could use a simple variable `foo` just as well.

If you do want to read the `grep` output lines into an array with one line per element, then there's the [**Bash Builtin Command**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html) `readarray`:

```
< <(grep name emp.txt) readarray foo
```

This uses the expansion [**Process Substitution**](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html).

> i want to replace some text can i use sed command in echo "$line"

Of course you can use `echo "$line" | sed …`.